# Best practice to install Tableau Server as IaC

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, devops, tableau-api

I am trying to figure it out which one is the best practice when creating a new server on `AWS EC2`.

To do that I choose `Tableau Server`. First time, as Tableau docs recommend I did the install myself, but I would like to keep as automatic as possible everything, the idea behind that is if ec2 get destroyed how can I recover everything fast?

I am using `terraform` to store as a code all the `AWS` infrastructure, but the installation itself is not automatic yet.

To do that, I have two options, `ansible` (never worked before) or in this particular case `Tableau` has an automated install script in `python`, which I could add in the `EC2` template launch configuration,and then using `terraform` I can raise it in minutes.

Which one should be the choosen why? Both seems to acomplish the final goal.

Also it raises some kind of doubs such as:

It retrieves the server up and with a full instalation of the software, but to get all users, and all the Tableau setup I have to raise anyways an snapshot, right? Is there any other tool to do that?

Then, if the manual install of the software is fast enough, why then I should use IaC to keep the install as code, instead of document the script of installation? And just keep the Infrastructure as code?